# wxPython - how to create a single frame with two inset panels?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I'm writing a program using wxPython as the GUI, and I'd like to make something akin to the (now seemingly outdated) traditional Windows help sections, with a tree/table of contents on the left, a vertical divider, and the contents of whatever page you selected in the tree on the right, where both the tree and the info are kind of inset into beveled areas on the screen. After searching through the docs (and SO), I can't seem to find out how to do this -- but I know it's possible. I've seen screenshots in the docs of frames like this, but there was no code provided (and the screenshots weren't on pages relating to how you would accomplish this -- I want to say it was on the page for tree views or something).

Attached is a screenshot of what I'm aiming for. It doesn't have to be as complex as the screenshot, I just want the general idea of a static tree or even just a list of links on the left which update the contents on the right, but with both panels set into beveled frames (in the common sense of the word) with a vertical bar in the middle.

Anyone know how to do this?

*EDIT* because people seem to be misinterpreting the question. I don't need anyone to write the code to produce a frame like that in the image for me. I just want to know if there is a way in wxPython to make the panels appear set into the frame, the way the tree and content sections in the image are. Simply setting two panels into one frame is trivial, but there's no visible border unless you add a `border=somevalue` parameter to the `sizer.Add()` call when setting up the frame, and then the 'divider' is just an unappealing gray area. Sorry I can't show code; if I knew the code to create such an inset panel, I wouldn't be here. I can show that I know how to add multiple panels to a single frame and dynamically update one panel based on events caught by handlers in another, if that would help, but I don't see that that's particularly relevant.

[image: sample]

Comment: Have you looked at `wx.SplitterWindow`?

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! If you post as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, a `wx.SplitterWindow` may be the closest fit to what you're looking for.
An example of a SplitterWindow in one of my projects:

[image]

It doesn't come close to replicating your example but it does illustrate the look and feel of the thing, a class managing two sub-windows.

Comment: This is for sure close enough! Nice EQ ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You've made no attempt to show us the work that you've done to try to make this work. Your question seems to be asking someone else to do all the work for you.

Here's a simple program that creates two panels with a tree on the left and a text control on the right. The rest is over to you

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.size = (400, 1000)
        self.Title = 'Two panels'

        self.help_panel = HelpPanel(self)
        self.index_panel = IndexPanel(self)
        panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        panel_sizer.Add(self.help_panel, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=5)
        panel_sizer.Add(self.index_panel)
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        main_sizer.Add(panel_sizer, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()


class IndexPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self, size=(200,400),  style=wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        sizer.Add(self.tree)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class HelpPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.tree = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(200,400),  style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer.Add(self.tree)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        wx_app = wx.App()
        MainFrame()
        wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: My question isn't asking someone to do any work for me; my question is asking if there exists a wxPython method that creates a divided frame similar to that in the image. The work I've done to try to get this to work is to search through the API docs. I know making a frame with two panels without any border will have no divider, and I know adding `border=somevalue` to the `sizer.Add()` call will make an unappealing gray area. There is no coding to be done if you can't find the method needed in the API docs. Thanks for showing me how to put two panels in one frame, though.